# Proof for exact differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am currently looking at the proof for why $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{t}}$ = $\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{y}}$.

Edit: Specifically, this is from "Differential Equations and Their Applications" by Marin Braun. It states, "Let $M(t, y)$ and $N(t, y)$ be continuous and have continuous partial derivatives with respect to t and y in the rectange R consisting of those points $(t, y)$ with a < t < b and c < y < d. There exists a function $\phi(t, y)$ such that $M(t, y)$ = $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t}}$ and $N(t, y) = \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{y}}$, if, and only if $\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{t}}$ = $\frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{y}}$.

In the proof, it states the following

$$\phi(t, y) = \int M(t, y)dt + h(y)$$

$$\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{y}} = \int \frac{\partial{M(t, y)}}{\partial{y}}dt + h'(y)$$

$$h'(y) = N(t, y) - \int\frac{\partial{M}(t,y)}{\partial{y}}dt$$.

It then states that "$h'(t)$ is a function of y alone, while the right-hand side appears to be a function of both t and y..."

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}[N(t,y) - \int\frac{\partial{M}(t,y)}{\partial{y}}dt] = \frac{\partial{N}}{\partial{t}}-\frac{\partial{M}}{\partial{y}} = 0.$$

However, isn't $y$ also a function of t, in that $h'(y)$ is actually $h'(y(t))$, so then $$\frac{\partial}{\partial{t}}(h'(y(t)) = \frac{\partial{h}}{\partial{y}}*\frac{dy}{dt}$$ rather than $0$?

I really appreciate any and all help on this.

Comment: Without the reference where you found this, is hard (almost impossible) answer this.

Comment: Sorry @azif00, just fixed it.

Comment: No to $y(t)$. While the question arises in the context of ODE, the claim itself is strictly about functions in 2 variables and their partial derivatives. Also known as Liouville theorem, condition that integrals $\int_p^q(M\,dt+N\,dy)$ are path-independent, ...

Comment: Looking at the theorem, $y$ is not a function of $t$ for the purpose of the theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do not know whether the function satisfies the two conditions $M(t, y)$ = $\frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{t}}$ and $N(t, y) = \frac{\partial{\phi}}{\partial{y}}$ exists, so we just suppose it exists. As you stated, "h′(y) is a function of y alone, while the right-hand side appears to be a function of both t and y..." yes, the right-hand side should be evaluated that indeed it is a function of $y$ alone, then our assumption is right.